# postgres deadlock without explicit locking

Tags: postgresql, deadlock, transaction

I use PostgreSQL 9.2, and I do not use explicit locking anywhere, neither `LOCK` statement nor `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. However, recently I got `ERROR: 40P01: deadlock detected`. The query where deadlock was detected is wrapped in transaction block though. Anyway, how comes it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose session 1 does:

```
begin transaction;
update a set col = val where pk = 1;
update a set col = val where pk = 2;
commit;
```

and at the exact same time session 2 does the opposite:

```
begin transaction;
update a set col = val where pk = 2;
update a set col = val where pk = 1;
commit;
```

Then session 1 will be waiting for session 2 to commit or rollback the update on the row where pk = 2 while at the same time session 2 will be waiting for session 1 to commit or rollback the update on the row where pk = 1. Deadlock.

Comment: Thx, by the way, will there be a deadlock in the same situation in MySQL?

Comment: I think most DBMSes will get a deadlock for this scenario.

Comment: @Zapadlo: yes, absolutely. Every DBMS will wind up in a deadlock situation with this example.